# Spring blocks access to Angular application

Tags: angular, spring, cors

I wrote a backend in Spring and added jwt authentication there. Placed above the controller `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")`. The controller with authentication works well, I can get a token and a user from the client, but when I already make a request to receive data, I need to pass this token in the Authorization header. I tested it via postman, everything works, but on Angular I make a request:

```
export class SensorsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getSensors(){
    let token = localStorage.getItem("token")
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    })

    const options = {headers}

    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/sensors", options).subscribe(res => console.log(res))
  }
}
```

And I get an error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/sensors' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

But why if I added `allowedHeaders="*"`

Comment: Do you already add proxy config in your Angular project? https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Comment: I have added, but got another error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74649793/proxy-doesnt-works-and-i-get-404-not-found